# Is it possible to use brunch with ampersand?

Tags: ampersand, brunch

I am trying to use ampersand with brunch instead of browserify but it causes some problems.

Here is the code :

```
"use strict";

var View = require("ampersand-view");

var HelloView = View.extend({
    autoRender: true,
    template: '<p>Hello</p>'
});

var app = new HelloView();

document.body.appendChild(app.el);
```

brunch-config file has :

```
npm:
    enabled: true
```

The brunch build command is OK but when I run the page in the browser I get :

```
View.extend is not a function
```

A console.log for the View object gives me a "function baseCopy()" object.

Is it not possible at all to use ampersand with brunch (without a browserify plugin) ?

Comment: Seems like this module is buggy for brunch-npm integration. Maybe try using bower until we'll fix it. Sorry for that!